# Add only checked items to a new list

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

Im having some problems. I have a checkedlistbox with some 40 names. I want to add the names that are checked to a new list. I seem to have problems with the for and if loop for this. Help anyone?

Comment: Can you post the code you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, it seems that there might already be a method of CheckedListBox for this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems.aspx

You can then iterate through that Collection to do what ever you want like:

```
foreach(object itemChecked in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems) {
    //Deal with each itemChecked object
}
```

or just cast straight to a List

```
List<SomeTypeUsedForTheItems> checkedItems = checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Cast<SomeTypeUsedForTheItems>().ToList()
```